# Updating data in relational database, without affecting the already existing relation

Tags: database-design, relational-database

How do database systems make their changes in relational data that contains a *partial* history? For example, in a contract management system, I have a maintenance contract for a company to maintain some products. These products will be linked with the maintenance contract (within the database). Now assume that I have maintained these products for over 2 years within this contract, and suddenly the product changes in attributes, then I need to change the information about the product. But if I do that, because of the relation with contracts, the information would tell me that I maintained the product **in it's changed attributes**, for over 2 years, which is not true!

Now assume I have a simple *Contracts* and *Products* relationship (M:M relationsip, so *Contracts_Products* junction table is needed) and another *Productattributes*, in relationship with *Products* (M:1 relationship). Since I do not change anything about the *Contract*, neither about the *Product*, just the *Productattributes*, what are possible solutions to keep the relationship for the past the same, while only changing a *Productattribute* for the upcoming time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your requirements, you need to separate properties of a product that change over time (e.g., supplier, operating temperature range, unit cost) from those that are invariant (e.g., description, color, weight).

Call the table that holds the invariant properties `ProductFixedAttributes` and the one that holds the changeable properties `ProductVariableAttributes`.  Then a row of your current `Products` table is 1-to-1 with `ProductVariableAttributes` and many-to-1 with `ProductFixedAttributes`, and you can drop the `Productattributes` table.

When a product's properties change, add a new row to `Products` that points to a new row in `ProductVariableAttributes` and an existing row in `ProductFixedAttributes`.  Use this new row for future associations with new `Contracts`; do not change the existing rows in `Contracts_Products`.